# duplicate entries in SQLite INSERT from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter, duplicates

When I run this query from codeigniter (PHP) on sqlite database i get duplicate inserts:

```
INSERT INTO `users` 
SELECT 'test@email.com' AS `email`,
'12345' AS `password`
```

When i run it from SQLite Manager, it only adds one entry.
HOWEVER, when i replace the above query with this in the PHP code:

```
INSERT INTO `users`
(`email`,`password`) 
VALUES ('test@email.com', '12345')
```

it only adds the entry once (everything else is the same). i also checked, the script gets called only once.

anyone has any ideas as to why that happens?
i know it can be fixed by setting email field to be primary key, then duplicates won't insert, but that's not an option.

Comment: so far the only solution i've found is to force a key that is unique (e.g. an ID field or email-password pair) that eliminates the duplicate entries, but that's only a work-around, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL syntax is the last one!

And why don't you use CodeIgniter's Active Record capabilities??

```
$data = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);
$this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

Comment: when i need to add multiple rows of data the query becomes: INSERT INTO `users` SELECT 'val' AS `email`, '123' AS `pass` UNION SELECT 'val2', 'pass2', etc... which is why i need the first SELECT in there. the sqlite syntax does not allow to do it the standard way, i.e. INSERT..... VALUES ('abc','123'), ('def','456'), etc.